# Bubble a's before b's with sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a file, which contains only a's and b's.

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbb
abababaaaabbbaabababa
bbbbbaaaaaa
aaabbbabbbaaaabbaba
abababbabbababbbabbab
abababbababaabaaabbababbaba
bababbbababba
```

I would like to sort all a's before b's with sed, like this:

```
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbb
    aaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbb
    aaaaaabbbbb
    aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbb
    aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbb
    ...
```

I tried to write this script

```
for row in $(sed -n 'p' $1)
do
    for k in $(seq $((${#row}-2)))
    do
        for j in $(seq $((${#row}-k-1)))
        do
           if [[  "${row:$j:1}" == a  &&  "${row:$j+1:1}" == b ]]; then
               sed -e  "s/./a/$j+1/p" $row  >> out.txt
           fi
        done
    done
done
```

But it doesn't work and I don't know really, how to make it work. But after writing this script, I realised that, I can do it maybe easier with sed labels.

But what I don't know, how do I set test condition in sed, which checks if 'a' is before 'b' or how can I set number of loops in sed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a file called test.txt and ran the following command:

```
sed -e ':loop' -e 's/ba/ab/' -e 't loop' test.txt
```

Comment: Why do you have to quote it separately like this? Why can you just use one quoting?

Comment: What exactly does the parameter -e? In manual pages there is written that it add the script to the commands to be executed. Does it mean that I have to use everytime, when I use multiple expressions in sed?

Comment: And last question... I don't really see what is the test condition. Is it just make it test, if all the substitutions were made or does it test something else?

Comment: @cutrightjm It's just [bubblesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), so `O(N^2)`.

Comment: @Muffy, sed -e ':label;othercommand` is not portable. In traditional sed implementations (and as was required by POSIX until recently), that defines a label called `label;othercommand`. That's why you need to need to split the code into several `-e expression`s or write it on several lines.

Answer (score 4):

A slightly more efficient way with `sed`:

```
sed 'h; s/b//g; x; s/a//g; H; x; s/\n//' file.txt
```

With `perl`:

```
perl -lpe '$_ = y/b//dr . y/a//dr' file.txt
```

Another way with `perl`:

```
perl -lpe '$_ = join "", sort split //' file.txt
```

(this works because `"a" lt "b"`).

With GNU `awk`:

```
awk '{ print gensub(/b/, "", "g") gensub(/a/, "", "g") }' file.txt
```

With `bash`:

```
while read -r line; do
    printf '%s%s\n' "$( tr -d b <<<"$line" )"  "$( tr -d a <<<"$line" )"
done <file.txt
```

Comment: Slightly shorter: `sed 'h;s/a//g;x;s/b//;G;s/\n//'`

Answer (score 1):

```
if [[  "${row:$j:1}" == a ...
```

If you're going this way, I think you could just do all of it in shell:

```
while read -r s ; do
    for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#s} ; i++ )) ; do 
        [ "${s:i:1}" = "a" ] && astr+=a || bstr+=b
    done
    echo "$astr$bstr"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pe 's/(b+)(a+)/$2$1/ while /ba/'  data.file
```

so long as a record comprises "b" followed by "a" we keep flipping the "islands" of bees and ayes in current record.

```
perl -F\(b+\) -lne '
   my @A;
   splice @A, (/b/ ? @A : 0), 0, $_  for @F;
   print @A;
' data.file
```

We initialize an array @A for every record/line read in. The fields carved out from the record (stored in @F) are examined and when they contain a "b" are pushed to the end of the array otherwise placed at the beginning. Finally we print the array.